# Visual Studio Express 2013 WPF warning: "The 'configuration' element is not defined"

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, app-config, visual-studio-express

Every WPF project I create in Visual Studio 2012 Express gives a warning right after creating the project:

> The 'configuration' element is not declared.

Projects compile if not accessing the config. When trying to access it (via ConfigurationManager or Properties), compilation fails. Does anyone have a clue what it may be?

Comment: That question was not answered. Please check your links before posting them next time.

Comment: because an answer was not selected as the correct answer does *not* mean that it was not answered... it has two answers and I *did* check before I commented. Please [search for a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question next time.